Is it possible to create two different Bigquery datasets with the same name but different location?
Is it possible to create two different BigQuery datasets with the same name but different location for the same project?

No, the dataset ID is a combination of the project and dataset name, not the location. Therefore, it would not be possible to uniquely address each dataset by location alone. To replicate data across different locations, you can use the new cross-region dataset replication feature. But I am not sure if that's what you are trying to accomplish.

No, it's not possible to create two BigQuery datasets with the same name but different locations. As per the limitations mentioned in this documentation, the Dataset names must be unique within the project.
The location of a BigQuery dataset is specified when it's created and cannot be changed.  However, if you want to recreate the Dataset in different location, you can follow the steps mentioned in this documentation.
